# Не распознается буква в Entry Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Всех приветствую!
Возникла следующая проблема - пользуюсь азерб алфавитом в tkinter и не распознается буква ə (ее unicode 0259)
Вместо буквы при вводе отображается '?'
Попытался реализовать замену,потерпел неудачу

```
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar
def replacing(*args):
    user_input = a.get()
    if 'ə' in user_input:
        user_input = re.sub('əƏ', '\u0259', user_input)
main_menu = tk.Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.trace_add('write',replacing)
a = tk.Entry(main_menu, textvariable = var)
main_menu.mainloop()
```

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным, и имеется ли у кого-то решение на этот счет?

Comment: Шрифт entry поддерживает азербайджанский алфавит?

Comment: Он распознает ç,ş,ğ,ö,ü. Единственная буква, которая не распознается это ə

Comment: Если сделать `var.set('əƏ')`, буквы выведется в entry?

Comment: По поводу замены - после замены текста в переменной, этот текст нужно обратно положить в текстовое поле.

Comment: Да, если сделать var.set('əƏ') этот метод, то буква выводится в entry

Comment: Насчет положить обратно в текстовое поле..т.е. присвоить var значение user_input?

Comment: Не присвоить, а установить через метод set

Comment: Но не факт, что это как-то поможет. Пробуйте делать принт того что вводится фактически. Если там действительно вопросы, то замена не поможет (разве что замена вопроса на нужную букву, но тогда и обычные вопросы будут заменяться). Возможно это баг в tk/tcl

Comment: В принтах так и выводится с вопросом. По сути замена вопроса на букву не критична, поскольку в Entry не используются вопросы

Comment: Ну, если не критично, то можно заменой закостылить, через обычный replace: `user_input = user_input.replace("?", "ə")`, потом `var.set(user_input)`

Comment: Вот можно посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846986/certain-characters-like-%C8%9B-and-%C8%99-become-question-marks-as-i-type-them-in-a-tkin.

Answer (score 0):

Решено добавлением костыля

```
user_input = entry.get()
if '?' in user_input:
    user_input = user_input.replace('?','ə')
    var.set(user_input)
```

По-другому проблема никак не решалась. Спасибо огромное tkinter за такой косяк))